# Create JS Stage events

Tags: javascript, createjs

"stagemouseup" already exists on the Stage object.
If I add it like this would I get multiple callbacks?

```
stage.addEventListener("stagemouseup", function(){window.open(window.clickTag);});
```

In my local testing only 1 window launches so it seemed safe.
However, after reading the docs it seems like this is the answer:

```
stage.on("stagemouseup", function(){window.open(window.clickTag);});
```

Can someone help me confirm?

Comment: Hi Kevin, is there a reason you commented? Just wondering why if you don't understand the subject matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the listener multiple times, you will get multiple callbacks on each click.

The `on()` method is a shortcut for `addEventListener` that has some syntactic sugar, such as:

1. passing a `scope` parameter (and implicit scope if none is passed, instead of defaulting to `window`)
2. A "run once" boolean
3. a data object that is passed through the the handler

There is also some functionality on the events dispatched by `on()`, which allow you to easily remove the handler.

http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/EventDispatcher.html#method_on

Comment: Thanks for the help Lanny!